# Data saved in service from promise cannot be accessed afterwards

Tags: angular7, es6-promise

I am using the Following simple function to call multiple promises:

```
  loadData() {
const promise1 = this.httpClient.post(this.baseURL, { params: params, headers: headers }).toPromise();
const promise2 = this.httpClient.post(this.baseURL, { params: params, headers: headers }).toPromise();
Promise.all([promise1,promise1]).then(res => {
  this.myService.save(res[0],res[1]);
});
```

}

My Service looks as follows:

```
  private result0 = [];
  private result1 = [];
  save(res0,res1) {
    this.result0 = res0;
    this.result1 = res1;
  }

  getResult1() {
    alert(this.res1);
  }
  getResult2() {
    alert(this.res1);
  }
```

and from some reason, i see the data when saved, but if i have another button calling one of the "getResult" functions i keep getting an empty array as the value of the service's private memebrs.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show component code?

Comment: youve declared result0 & result1 but are then trying to access res1 & res2